# jquery help assigning multiple mouse events using a .each() to hide/show icons and show background color

Tags: jquery

Need some help assigning a mouseover event to display some icons that start out hidden.

For every `<li>` in the `ul`, I have icons.  When the user mouses over the `<li>` I want the span tag with a class called "icons" to be displayed.  When the mouse out event occurs remove the class and/or just hide the span.  The problem for me is how to assign event so just the span tag and its contents appear and disapear when the mouse hovers over the `<li>`.

Heres the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
     <li>Cat 1
          <span class="icons">
              <div>stuff here</div>
          </span>
     </li>
     <li>Cat 2
          <span class="icons">
              <div>stuff here</div>
          </span>
             <ul>
                 <li>Sub Cat 2A
                     <span class="icons">
                         <div>2A stuff here</div>
                     </span>
                 </li>
             </ul>  
     </li>
</ul>
```

Heres my jquery code.

```
$('#nav li').each(function(){

                //Add Background Shading o Mouseover to all Rows in the menu
                $(this).mouseover(function(){ 
                        $(this).addClass("background_grey").removeClass("icons"); 
                })

                $(this).mouseout(function(){ 
                        $(this).removeClass("background_grey").addClass("icons"); 
                });
        });
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ronedog - Added another alternative, probably much easier to maintain, just be aware you have shorter options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the `each()` function for this. The `mouseout()` and `mouseover()` functions will will apply to all elements returned by your selector.

```
$('#nav li').mouseover(function(){ 
    ...
}).mouseout(function(){ 
    ...
});
```

Now to access the span inside of the element which was hovered, you would use the `find()` function.

```
    $(this).find("span").removeClass("icons"); 

    $(this).find("span").addClass("icons");
```

Lastly, you should use `mouseenter/mouseleave` in preference to `mouseover/mouseout` since you don't want your hide event to fire when you enter the `span` element.

```
$('#nav li').mouseenter(function(){ 
    $(this).addClass("background_grey")
    .find("span").removeClass("icons"); 
}).mouseleave(function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass("background_grey")
    .find("span").addClass("icons"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joel.  That's exactly what I needed.  I didn't even think of using .find()....show's my noobie credentials. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten it all down using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
$('#nav li').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("background_grey").find(".icons").toggle(); 
});
```

This toggles the background class whether the `.icons` spans are shown on hover, the opposite on mouseout.